# I have a problem with train my GAN model, i dont know how to fix it

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, generative-adversarial-network

I have been working on it for a week now, I corrected error after error, but I was already tired, so I decided to ask if they could help me here, GPT also asked, he didn’t help much

This is the code of model GAN neural network:

```py
from keras.layers import Dropout
from keras.models import Sequential, Model
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout
from keras.layers import Reshape
from keras.layers.core import Activation
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LeakyReLU
from tensorflow.keras.layers import BatchNormalization
from keras.layers.convolutional import UpSampling2D
from keras.layers.convolutional import Convolution2D
from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv2D
from keras.layers import Input, LSTM, RepeatVector, Lambda
from keras.layers.core import Flatten
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras import backend as K
import numpy as np
import sys, glob
import cv2
import os
import pytest
import argparse


def generator_model(inputdim = 100, xdim = 4, ydim = 4):
    # xdim = 2, ydim = 2 results in prediction shape of (1, 3, 32, 32)
    # xdim = 4, ydim = 4 results in prediction shape of (1, 3, 64, 64)
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Reshape((inputdim,), input_shape=(inputdim,)))  # Изменение размерности входного тензора
    model.add(Dense(units=1024 * xdim * ydim))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(Reshape((1024, xdim, ydim), input_shape=(1024 * xdim * ydim,)))  # Изменение размерности выходного тензора
    model.add(UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2)))
    model.add(Convolution2D(512, 5, 5, padding='same'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2)))
    model.add(Convolution2D(256, 5, 5,padding='same'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2)))
    model.add(Convolution2D(128, 5, 5,padding='same'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2)))
    model.add(Convolution2D(3, 5, 5,padding='same'))
    model.add(Activation('tanh'))
    return model

def discriminator_model():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), input_shape=(27, 1, 3), padding='same'))
    model.add(Conv2D(128, 5, strides=(2, 2), input_shape=(64, 64, 3), padding='same'))
    model.add(LeakyReLU(0.2))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(Conv2D(256, 5, strides=(2, 2), padding='same'))
    model.add(LeakyReLU(0.2))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(Conv2D(512, (5, 5), strides=(2, 2), padding='same', data_format='channels_last'))
    model.add(LeakyReLU(0.2))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(Conv2D(1024, (5, 5), strides=(2, 2), padding='same', data_format='channels_last'))
    model.add(LeakyReLU(0.2))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
    model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
    return model

def va_model(batch_size=5, original_dim = 5, latent_dim = 10, intermediate_dim = 20, epsilon_std = 0.01):
    # Generate probabilistic encoder (recognition network), which
    # maps inputs onto a normal distribution in latent space.
    # The transformation is parametrized and can be learned.
    x = Input(batch_shape=(batch_size, original_dim))
    h = Dense(intermediate_dim, activation='relu')(x)
    z_mean = Dense(latent_dim)(h)
    z_log_sigma = Dense(latent_dim)(h)

    def sampling(args):
        z_mean, z_log_sigma = args
        epsilon = K.random_normal(shape=(batch_size, latent_dim),
                                  mean=0., std=epsilon_std)
        return z_mean + K.exp(z_log_sigma) * epsilon

    # note that "output_shape" isn't necessary with the TensorFlow backend
    # so you could write `Lambda(sampling)([z_mean, z_log_sigma])`
    z = Lambda(sampling, output_shape=(latent_dim,))([z_mean, z_log_sigma])
    decoder_h = Dense(intermediate_dim, activation='relu')
    decoder_mean = Dense(original_dim, activation='sigmoid')
    h_decoded = decoder_h(z)
    x_decoded_mean = decoder_mean(h_decoded)
    return x, x_decoded_mean, z_mean


def vaencoder_model():
    x, x_decoded_mean, z_mean = va_model(batch_size=5, original_dim = 5, latent_dim = 10, intermediate_dim = 20, epsilon_std = 0.01)
    # end-to-end autoencoder
    vae = Model(x, x_decoded_mean)
    # encoder, from inputs to latent space
    encoder = Model(x, z_mean)
    return encoder, vae

def generator_containing_discriminator(generator, discriminator):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(generator)
    discriminator.trainable = False
    model.add(discriminator)
    #discriminator.trainable = False
    return model
```

This is the code to train the GAN model:

```py
import argparse
import os
os.environ['QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH'] = '/home/hotdog/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cv2/qt/plugins'
import cv2
import numpy as np
import glob
import os
import model
from model import generator_containing_discriminator
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LeakyReLU
import scipy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.optimizers import SGD,RMSprop
import os, struct
from array import array as pyarray
from numpy import append, array, int8, uint8, zeros
import numpy as np


def load_image(path):
    ''' Resize image to 64x64 and shuffle axis to create 3 arrays (RGB) '''
    img = cv2.imread(path, 1)
    img = np.float32(cv2.resize(img, (64, 64))) / 127.5 - 1
    img = np.rollaxis(img, 2, 0)
    return img

def noise_image():
    ''' Create noisy data that will be converted to an image
        Note size = (total number, number in sublist, length of subsublist )
    '''
    zmb = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, 100)
    #zmb = np.random.uniform(0, 1, 100)
    return zmb

def chunks(l, n):
    """Yield successive n-sized chunks from l."""
    for i in range(0, len(l), n):
        yield l[i:i+n]

def train(path, batch_size, EPOCHS):

    # reproducibility
    np.random.seed(42)
    fig = plt.figure()

    # Get image paths
    print("Loading paths..")
    paths = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.jpg"))
    print("Got paths..")

    # Load images
    IMAGES = np.array([load_image(p) for p in paths])
    np.random.shuffle(IMAGES)

    BATCHES = [b for b in chunks(IMAGES, batch_size)]

    discriminator = model.discriminator_model()
    generator = model.generator_model()
    discriminator_on_generator = model.generator_containing_discriminator(generator, discriminator)
    adam_gen=Adam(lr=0.00002, beta_1=0.0005, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-08)
    adam_dis=Adam(lr=0.00002, beta_1=0.0005, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-08)
    opt = RMSprop()
    generator.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=adam_gen)
    discriminator_on_generator.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=adam_gen)
    discriminator.trainable = True
    discriminator.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=adam_dis)

    print("Number of batches", len(BATCHES))
    print("Batch size is", batch_size)

    margin = 0.25
    equilibrium = 0.6931
    inter_model_margin = 0.10

    for epoch in range(EPOCHS):

        print("Epoch", epoch)

        # load weights on first try (i.e. if process failed previously and we are attempting to recapture lost data)
        if epoch == 0:
            if os.path.exists('generator_weights') and os.path.exists('discriminator_weights'):
                print("Loading saved weights..")
                generator.load_weights('generator_weights')
                discriminator.load_weights('discriminator_weights')
                print("Finished loading")
            else:
                pass

        for index, image_batch in enumerate(BATCHES):
            print("Epoch", epoch, "Batch", index)

            Noise_batch = np.array([noise_image() for n in range(len(image_batch))])
            generated_images = generator.predict(Noise_batch)
            print(generated_images[0][-1][-1])
            print("Shape of image_batch:", image_batch.shape)
            print("Shape of generated_images:", generated_images.shape)

            for i, img in enumerate(generated_images):
                rolled = np.rollaxis(img, 0, 3)
                rolled = np.squeeze(rolled)  # Remove the extra dimension
                rgb_image = cv2.cvtColor(rolled, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
                cv2.imwrite('results/' + str(i) + ".jpg", np.uint8(255 * 0.5 * (rgb_image + 1.0)))

            generated_images = np.repeat(generated_images, 64, axis=3)
            print("Shape of generated_images after repeat:", generated_images.shape)
            print("Dimension of image_batch:", image_batch.ndim)
            # Expand dimensions of the image_batch array
            expanded_image_batch = np.expand_dims(image_batch, axis=1)
            repeated_image_batch = np.repeat(expanded_image_batch, generated_images.shape[1], axis=1)

            # Reshape the generated_images array to have 4 dimensions
            reshaped_generated_images = np.reshape(generated_images, (1024, 27, 3, 8))
            reshaped_generated_images1 = np.expand_dims(reshaped_generated_images, axis=1)

            # Concatenate the repeated_image_batch and reshaped_generated_images arrays
            Xd = np.concatenate((repeated_image_batch, reshaped_generated_images1), axis=1)


            print("Shape of image_batch:", image_batch.shape)
            print("Shape of generated_images:", generated_images.shape)



            yd = [1] * len(image_batch) + [0] * len(image_batch)  # labels

            print("Training first discriminator..")
            d_loss = discriminator.train_on_batch(Xd, yd)

            Xg = Noise_batch
            yg = [1] * len(image_batch)

            print("Training first generator..")
            g_loss = discriminator_on_generator.train_on_batch(Xg, yg)

            print("Initial batch losses: Generator loss", g_loss, "Discriminator loss", d_loss, "Total:", g_loss + d_loss)

            print("equilibrium - margin", equilibrium - margin)

            if g_loss < d_loss and abs(d_loss - g_loss) > inter_model_margin:
                while abs(d_loss - g_loss) > inter_model_margin:
                    print("Updating discriminator..")
                    g_loss = discriminator_on_generator.train_on_batch(Xg, yg)
                    d_loss = discriminator.train_on_batch(Xd, yd)
                    print("Generator loss", g_loss, "Discriminator loss", d_loss)
                    if d_loss < g_loss:
                        break
            elif d_loss < g_loss and abs(d_loss - g_loss) > inter_model_margin:
                while abs(d_loss - g_loss) > inter_model_margin:
                    print("Updating generator..")
                    d_loss = discriminator.train_on_batch(Xd, yd)
                    g_loss = discriminator_on_generator.train_on_batch(Xg, yg)
                    print("Generator loss", g_loss, "Discriminator loss", d_loss)
                    if g_loss < d_loss:
                        break
            else:
                pass

            print("Final batch losses (after updates): Generator loss", g_loss, "Discriminator loss", d_loss, "Total:", g_loss + d_loss)
            print

            if index % 20 == 0:
                print('Saving weights..')
                generator.save_weights('generator_weights', True)
                discriminator.save_weights('discriminator_weights', True)

        plt.clf()
        for i, img in enumerate(generated_images[:5]):
            i = i+1
            plt.subplot(3, 3, i)
            rolled = np.rollaxis(img, 0, 3)
            rolled = np.squeeze(rolled)  # Remove the extra dimension
            rgb_image = cv2.cvtColor(rolled, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            plt.imshow(rgb_image)
            plt.axis('off')
        fig.canvas.draw()
        plt.savefig('Epoch_' + str(epoch) + '.png')

def generate(img_num):
    '''
        Generate new images based on the trained model.
    '''
    generator = model.generator_model()
    adam = Adam(lr=0.00002, beta_1=0.0005, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-08)
    generator.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=adam)
    generator.load_weights('generator_weights')

    noise = np.array([noise_image() for n in range(img_num)])

    print('Generating images..')
    generated_images = [np.rollaxis(img, 0, 3) for img in generator.predict(noise)]
    for index, img in enumerate(generated_images):
        cv2.imwrite("{}.jpg".format(index), np.uint8(255 * 0.5 * (img + 1.0)))

def get_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--path", type=str)
    parser.add_argument("--TYPE", type=str)
    parser.add_argument("--batch_size", type=int, default=50)
    parser.add_argument("--epochs", type=int, default=2)
    parser.add_argument("--handicap", type=int, default=2)
    parser.add_argument("--img_num", type=int, default=10)

    args = parser.parse_args()
    return args

if __name__ == "__main__":

    args = get_args()

    if args.TYPE == 'train':
        train(path=args.path, batch_size=args.batch_size, EPOCHS=args.epochs)

    elif args.TYPE == 'generate':
        generate(img_num=args.img_num)
```

[image]

[image]

This the error that appears when I start training my model:

[image]

This model is a neural network that needs to load a dataset, train and draw something of its own.

Comment: Can you tell from the error message, that the problem is in the `reshaped_generated_images = np.reshape(generated_images, (1024, 27, 3, 8))` line?  `reshape` works only if the new shape total elements (1024*27*3*8) matches the size of `generated_images`.  According to the error the image is too large to reshape to this shape.

Comment: You've done several things to `generated_images` and displayed its shape. Those numbers have to match, in some sense or other, with the `reshape`.  Those are details that YOU have to keep track off.

Comment: @hpaulj I understand that the problem is in the "reshape", but I don't understand how to fix it, I spent too much time on fixing other errors and now I can't think normally, do you know how to fix it? Maybe it's easy to make an array bigger?

Comment: Please don't post images of text.

Comment: @pppery Why not?

Comment: [It's explained here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)